# Using regex or string delimiter to get the expected value from the dictionary

Tags: python, regex, string, list, dictionary

I have a dict in python list shown below where the key is the interface and value is the string. I need to convert the value to int but cannot because of the strings for eg.100-110. Should i use a regex or is there a simple way out to find out 2 in the string values that I got from the dict. May be use regex or string delimiter to separate using hyphen and then find number 2 in the range. Or once I use the string de-limiter should I convert that to range of some sort.

The numbers seperated by hyphen are the range for eg 100-110. Once I have the range I can verify the no. 2 falls in that range and get the corresponding interface. Sometimes the strings may be in this pattern `4,6,7,8,12-15,8`. Need to find the no.2 falls in this pattern and it also has the hyphen.

[{'eth1/1': '100-110', 'eth1/2': '100-110', 'eth1/3': '1-4094', 'eth1/4': '1-4094', 'eth1/5': '1-4094', 'eth1/6': '1-4094', 'eth1/7': '1-4094', 'eth1/8': '1-4094', 'eth1/9': '1-4094', 'eth1/10': '1-4094', 'eth1/11': '1-4094', 'eth1/12': '1-4094', 'eth1/13': '2,5-10,49,59,66', 'eth1/14': '1-4094', 'eth1/15': '1-4094', 'eth1/16': '1-4094', 'eth1/17': '1-4094', 'eth1/18': '1-4094', 'eth1/19': '1-4094', 'eth1/20': '2,5-10,49,59,66', 'eth1/21': '1-4094', 'eth1/22': '1-4094', 'eth1/23': '1-4094', 'eth1/24': '1-4094', 'eth1/25': '1-4094', 'eth1/26': '1-4094', 'eth1/27': '1-4094', 'eth1/28': '1-4094', 'eth1/29': '1-4094', 'eth1/30': '1-4094', 'eth1/31': '1-4094', 'eth1/32': '1-4094', 'eth1/33': '1-4094', 'eth1/34': '1-4094', 'eth1/35': '2,5-10,49,59,66', 'eth1/36': '1-4094', 'eth1/37': '1-4094', 'eth1/38': '1-4094', 'eth1/39': '1-4094', 'eth1/40': '1-4094', 'eth1/41': '1-4094', 'eth1/42': '1-4094', 'eth1/43': '1-4094', 'eth1/44': '2,5-10,49,59,66', 'eth1/45': '1-4094', 'eth1/46': '1-4094', 'eth1/47': '1-4094', 'eth1/48': '1-4094'}]

Comment: Does seem like with the data you have, that you could use `.split('-')` alone instead of regex to separate the two values (& then parse as numbers as you please).

Comment: Why is the dictionary in a list? Can there be multiple dictionaries in the list?

Comment: @JanKyuPeblik It's not always 2 values. It's a mix of comma-separated numbers and ranges.

Comment: @Barmar There could be a possibility of multiple dicts if I were to make API calls to multiple switches. so a list of dicts. In this case I am testing for one switch where I can find out vlan 2 exists in the values I retrieved. This could be range or comma seperated values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a function that takes one of those strings and tests whether a value is in it:

```
def in_nums_or_ranges(n, list_string):
    values = list_string.split(',')
    for item in values:
        if item.isnumeric():
            if n == int(item):
                return True
        else:
            start, end = map(int, item.split('-'))
            if n in range(start, end+1):
                return True
    return False
```

Then to find the dictionary elements that match:

```
search_val = 2
matches = {key: value for key, value in d.items() if in_nums_or_ranges(search_val, value)}
```